# How to set up a UWP class library with the new csproj format with MSBuild.Extras?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, msbuild, csproj

I'm trying to create a class library that uses UWP controls (the lower the version the better), and I want it to use the new *csproj* format.

I figured [MSBuild.Sdk.Extras](https://github.com/novotnyllc/MSBuildSdkExtras) is what I'm after.
After reading the Readme I did the following:

1. I created a .NET Standard class library project and replaced its content with the following:

```xml
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>uap</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

2. I added a *global.json* file with the following content:

```
{
  "msbuild-sdks": {
    "MSBuild.Sdk.Extras": "2.0.54"
  }
}
```

But when I try to build the project, I get the following error:

> D:\Users\Shimmy\Source\Repos....csproj : error  : The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" cannot be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long.  >C:\Users\Shimmy.nuget\packages\msbuild.sdk.extras\2.0.54\Build\Platforms\Windows.targets

I'm willing to hear about other ways of UWP creating class libraries as long as it uses the new format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```xml
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>uap10.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Or one of the specific versions, i.e. `uap10.0.16299`.